# How to sum values using for function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sum

I need your help. I have created looping function which is FOR to sum the values for specific column.

```
var result = data.result; //declare result as variable
var rows = result.result.rows; //declare rows as variable
// var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; rows.length > i; i++) {
  var column = "";
  var total = total_event_loss;
  var sum += parseFloat(rows[i][total_event_loss]);
  column += "<tr><td><center>" + rows[i][category] + "</center></td>";
  column += "<td><center><div class='font-red'>" + sum + "</div>" + rows[i][pic] + "</center></td>";
  column += "<td><center><div class='font-red'>" + rows[i][total_event_loss] + "</div>" + rows[i][field] + "<br/>" + rows[i][sub_category] + "</center></td></tr>";
  $(column).appendTo(container.find("table > tbody"));
}
```

Comment: You should declare `var sum=0` outside the loop... where you already commented it out. The way you have it now it resets every iteration of the loop

Comment: You can't write `var sum += ...`. `var` is used to initialize a new variable, you can't add to it at the same time as you're initializing.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the `sum` variable before the loop, and add to it inside the loop. You can't use the `var` keyword when adding to it.

```
var result = data.result;
var rows = result.result.rows;
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; rows.length > i; i++) {
  var column = "";
  sum += parseFloat(rows[i][total_event_loss]);
  column += "<tr><td><center>" + rows[i][category] + "</center></td>";
  column += "<td><center><div class='font-red'>" + sum + "</div>" + rows[i][pic] + "</center></td>";
  column += "<td><center><div class='font-red'>" + rows[i][total_event_loss] + "</div>" + rows[i][field] + "<br/>" + rows[i][sub_category] + "</center></td></tr>";
  $(column).appendTo(container.find("table > tbody"));
}
```

You also never use the `total` variable, I removed that.

BTW, comments like `declare result as a variable` are pretty useless. Code comments should clarify things that might not be obvious. It's clear that a `var` statement declares a variable.